# Got some problems with building an html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm making a table and I got a few problems that I can't solve without help,namely:

1. I need all `<td>` to be the same height as it's respective `<tr>`. `height:100%` doesn't work for all `<td>` for some reason, however fixed height works.
2. `<tbody>` is smaller than `<table>` itself which leads to the gap on the right side.
3. I want all borders to be 1px, but some of them are more bold. How do I make them all uniform?

https://codepen.io/NoOneKnowsWhoIam/pen/rzweRV

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.caption {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: grey;
}

.quarter-width {
  width: 25%;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.third-width {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <caption class="caption"><b>ST CLARE ZNNR5</b></caption>
    <tr>
      <td><b>11:39  01.07.2017</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="half-width"><b>MMSI 235002514</b></td>
      <td class="half-width text-right"><b>IMO 09236949</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
              Пассажирское судно, в пути<br>
              86 м × 18 м × 2.5 м
            </b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="half-width">
        Координаты<br>
        <b>50 47. 2000 N</b><br>
        <b>001 06. 4000  W</b>
      </td>
      <td class="half-width text-right">
        Время с момента получения отчета<br>
        <b>9 с</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="half-width">
        Пункт назначения<br>
        <b>Port Fish</b>
      </td>
      <td class=" fixim half-width text-right">
        Расчетное время прибытия<br>
        <b>
              2017-07-01 17:15
              <b>(UTC)</b>
        </b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td class="quarter-width">
        COG<br>
        <b>329°</b>
      </td>
      <td class="quarter-width">
        COG<br>
        <b>329°</b>
      </td>
      <td class="quarter-width">
        HDG<br>
        <b>323°</b>
      </td>
      <td class="quarter-width">
        LOG<br>
        <b>_</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Спланированный маршрут</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="third-width"><b>ПТ №1</b></td>
      <td class="third-width">
        Tдв<br>
        <b>12:57:19</b>
      </td>
      <td class="third-width">
        D<br>
        <b>40.162 миль</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Рассчитать маршрут</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are using `td { display: inline-block; }` which causes serious problems. Better remove that. Then use `colspan` where needed to get cells that are wider than 1 spot in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `display: inline-block;` from the rule for `td` - this cancels their table-cell property, causing the problems you describe:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.caption {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: grey;
}

.quarter-width {
  width: 25%;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.third-width {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <caption class="caption"><b>ST CLARE ZNNR5</b></caption>
    <tr>
      <td><b>11:39  01.07.2017</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="half-width"><b>MMSI 235002514</b></td>
      <td class="half-width text-right"><b>IMO 09236949</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>
              Пассажирское судно, в пути<br>
              86 м × 18 м × 2.5 м
            </b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="half-width">
        Координаты<br>
        <b>50 47. 2000 N</b><br>
        <b>001 06. 4000  W</b>
      </td>
      <td class="half-width text-right">
        Время с момента получения отчета<br>
        <b>9 с</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="half-width">
        Пункт назначения<br>
        <b>Port Fish</b>
      </td>
      <td class=" fixim half-width text-right">
        Расчетное время прибытия<br>
        <b>
              2017-07-01 17:15
              <b>(UTC)</b>
        </b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td class="quarter-width">
        COG<br>
        <b>329°</b>
      </td>
      <td class="quarter-width">
        COG<br>
        <b>329°</b>
      </td>
      <td class="quarter-width">
        HDG<br>
        <b>323°</b>
      </td>
      <td class="quarter-width">
        LOG<br>
        <b>_</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Спланированный маршрут</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="third-width"><b>ПТ №1</b></td>
      <td class="third-width">
        Tдв<br>
        <b>12:57:19</b>
      </td>
      <td class="third-width">
        D<br>
        <b>40.162 миль</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Рассчитать маршрут</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, will never do that again. But how do I divide 3 and 4 <td> into equal parts? Can't to do that with colspans.

Comment: In this case you'd have to use 12 TDs per row and use colspans on all cells: colspan 3 for 4 cells per row, colspan 4 for 3 cells, colspan 6 for 2 cells etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. If i wanna divide a row into, say, 3 equal parts, should I add additional 9 empty <td>? I don't see the logic behind it, could you elaborate, please?

Comment: No, you use 3 TDs, each having colspan = 4. Or 4 TDs each having colspan 3. The complicated thing about it is that every row has to add up to 12 columns, so you'll have to use a colspan attribute in pretty much every cell. So you actually never have 12 cells/columns, but you can use any division of 12, like 6, 4, 3 and 2 cells per row.

Comment: Got it, thanks for taking your time. I made it work but the only problem that is left is that cells' size is based on their content. The more words I add to a column the wider it gets. How can I prevent that?

Comment: You can still define a width for TDs (preferably via a class)